# Botframework reminder chatbot

Tags: c#, botframework

Does anyone know how they made bot like [this](https://www.messenger.com/t/mereminder) and [this?](https://www.messenger.com/t/helloimjarvis) I am using BotFramework V4 and C# and i need to make a reminder feature like this.Does this use proactive bot? and if yes can someone explain in layman how proactive bot works? Thanks!

Update:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That likely uses proactive messaging, yes. I'm not sure if either of those use Bot Framework, but to do that in Bot Framework, you'll need proactive messaging.

**Samples:**

- [C#](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages)
- [Node](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages)

A proactive message is generally either:

1. A message sent to a user that hasn't spoken with the bot before ([this is how Teams defines it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive)), or
2. A message sent to a user that the bot has spoken with previously, but the message being sent is not really a part of the previous conversation ([this is more how Bot Framework defines it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp))

Please see the docs linked above for more detail.

The gist of it, however, is that when a user talks with the bot, you save a reference to that conversation. At any future date that you want to talk to that user, you use that reference of the conversation (because it contains all of the pertinent user data) to message the user.

The tricky part with something like a reminder, however, is having the bot perform it at a particular time. Something like `Task.Delay` doesn't work very well at scale over long periods of time. The best thing to do for long, time-based delays would be set up some kind of other server to keep track of the time. Once that time expires, send a request to the bot to send the proactive message. The Proactive Sample does something kind of like the last part of that by accepting requests at [`api/notify`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs#L17).

Comment: Hi Sir Richardson. Is the sample working? I tried it and got an error when i visit "http://localhost:3978/api/notify". The error is "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.ICredentialProvider' while attempting to activate 'ProactiveBot.Controllers.NotifyController'."

Comment: Did it throw the error right away? What channel were you testing with (emulator, teams, web chat, etc)? Could be a [trustServiceUrl issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors). @user10860402

Comment: I was testing on emulator. It is responding to chat. It only produces the error when i go to localhost:3978/api/notify.

Comment: @user10860402 Interesting. It's working for me just fine. Did you make any changes to the sample?

Comment: I did not change anything sir. I updated the questions with images.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Please try adding [trustServiceUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors)

Comment: Sorry but where exactly should i put that line?

Comment: @user10860402 In that sample, it would go in `NotifyController.cs` before line 58. Generally, you want it to go just before you send a proactive message.

Comment: Sir richardson i have a new questions about the latest design of bot framework. hope you have time to check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57270112/obj-reference-not-set-error-when-calling-dialogs-by-interruptions-c-sharp-botra